# Python 3 as default Python command

Tags: command-line, python, python3, python-2.7, budgie

I am using Visual Studio Code for my Python programming and the problem that I am facing is that on terminal when I type the command `python`, **by default Python 2.7 is loaded.** So because of this I am not able to debug my Python 3 commands on my Ubuntu Budgie.

What should I do in order to uninstall Python 2.7 and make 3.7 as my default Python? I have uninstalled Python 2.7 by using the command `sudo apt-get remove python`. Even after doing this, I have to type `python3` to load Python 3.7 and **I get an error** when just I type `python`.

How do I make my **Python 3 default** so that when I type `python`, Python 3.7 starts?

-Codec Leaper

Comment: Just use `python3' both at command line and as first line in any python files. Ubuntu uses python3 for many internal thing, a few applications have not been converted yet & still use python2.  But you should always be specific in version you want. Never ever remove python. That will break system.

Comment: What version of Ubuntu?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The simplest is to make an alias in your **.bashrc**.

To do so open your .bashrc with:

```
nano ~/.bashrc
```

or

```
nano ~/.bash_aliases
```

and add  in the section **# some more aliases** a new  line containing

```
alias python='python3'
```

Open a new terminal and it should work fine.

**NOTE:** It's not recommended to make a symbolic link in your /usr/bin.

**For visual studio code:** The settings for python3 has to be set within the program - look at this [link](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/python/environments) how to set the right python path.

Comment: Na man, this was my question from the start 

Comment: you are using visual code, you put that later in your question. However, i would use the instruction from the link i gave you. further i suggest to use anaconda. python is to strongly involved in ubuntu, that it is better to set up a totally different python environment.

Comment: `nano ~/.bashrc` or `~/.bash_aliases`